# How to show 5 records on 20 rows table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

How to show less than 2 records on 20 fixed rows of a table ? I mean, i just want to show less records not looping them on 20 rows, i want to remain rows still empty. Something like picture below.
[image]

what i tried so far, i keeps getting last record looping until row 20.
I tried,

```
<table>
<?
$sql = "SELECT name, address, phone FROM contact";
$query = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
for($i=0;$i<=20;$i++)
{
   odbc_fetch_row($query);
   $name = odbc_result($query,"name");
   $address = odbc_result($query,"address");
   $phone = odbc_result($query,"phone");
?>
   <tr>
      <td><? echo $name;?></td>
      <td><? echo $name;?></td>
      <td><? echo $name;?></td>
      <td><? echo $name;?></td>
   </tr>
<?
} 
?>
</table>
```

And this is the result i got

[image]

So, how to make last record not looping ? thank you

Comment: have you considered using  `odbc_result_all ()`? Prints all rows from a result identifier produced by odbc_exec(). The result is printed in HTML table format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`odbc_fetch_row()` will return false if there is no data to display, so just check this first and set the variables accordingly...

```
   if (odbc_fetch_row($query)) {
       $name = odbc_result($query,"name");
       $address = odbc_result($query,"address");
       $phone = odbc_result($query,"phone");
   }
   else {
       $name = "";
       $address = "";
       $phone = "";
   }
```

You could also set a flag if you wish to stop the call altogether, the flag is set from the call to fetch the new data...

```
$moreData = true;
for($i=0;$i<=20;$i++)
{
   if ($moreData && $moreData = odbc_fetch_row($query)) {
       $name = odbc_result($query,"name");
       $address = odbc_result($query,"address");
       $phone = odbc_result($query,"phone");
   }
   else {
       $name = "";
       $address = "";
       $phone = "";
   }    ?>
   <tr>
      <td><? echo $name;?></td>
      <td><? echo $name;?></td>
      <td><? echo $name;?></td>
      <td><? echo $name;?></td>
   </tr>
<?
}
```